# unable to access Wordpress dyanmic css after and before content

Tags: php, css, wordpress

i try to get icon font through content with wordpress dyanmic css after and before content output is always 0

dynamic css

```
$back_top_before= absint(get_theme_mod( 'back_top_before', '"\f143"' ));
```

css

```
.back_top:before{
    content:"$back_top_before";
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:'amazing-neo';
}
```

Customizing setting

```
$wp_customize->add_setting(
        'back_top_before',
        array(
            'type' => 'theme_mod',
            'default'           => '',
            'sanitize_callback' => 'circle_sanitize_text'
        )
    );
    $wp_customize->add_control(
        new WP_Customize_Color_Control(
        $wp_customize, 
        'back_top_before', array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'label'      => esc_html__( 'Back to top icon', 'circle' ),
            'section'    => 'circle_back_to_top_settings',
            'settings'   => 'back_top_before',
        ) )
    );
```

Comment: I don't at all understand what the absint is there for. You appear to be trying to retrieve a value from the database, with a backup value unicode-type character-string and then converting it to an integer. Could you explain what this is for, thanks.

Comment: What @AHaworth said + you're trying to use a `php` variable (i.e "$back_top_before") inside a `css` rule. I don't understand your question either. Please edit your question and explain more.